# Python error: could not convert string to float

Tags: python, string, floating-point, text-files

I have some Python code that pulls strings out of a text file:

```
[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854, ....]
```

Python code:

```
v = string[string.index('['):].split(',')
for elem in v:
    new_list.append(float(elem))
```

This gives an error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [2.974717463860223e-06
```

Why can't `[2.974717463860223e-06` be converted to a float?

Comment: Do you see the `[` in your error message?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've still got the `[` in front of your "float" which prevents parsing.

Why not use a proper module for that? For example:

```
>>> a = "[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]"
>>> import json
>>> b = json.loads(a)
>>> b
[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]
```

or

```
>>> import ast
>>> b = ast.literal_eval(a)
>>> b
[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]
```

Comment: @Akavall `eval` is unsafe because it will evaluate arbitrary code.  `literal_eval` will only evaluate certain data structure code, such as lists, dicts, bools, and `None`.

Answer (score 5):

You may do the following to convert your string that you read from your file to a list of float

```
>>> instr="[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]"
>>> [float(e) for e in instr.strip("[] \n").split(",")]
[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]
```

The reason your code is failing is, you are not stripping of the '[' from the string.

Comment: If `json.loads` or `ast.literal_eval` did not exist, this would be the best way to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 3):

You are capturing the first bracket, change `string.index("[")` to `string.index("[") + 1`

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of floats without the need for extra imports etc.

```
s = '[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]'
s = s[1:-1]
float_list = [float(n) for n in s.split(',')]
```

```
[2.467188005806714e-05, 0.18664554919828535, 0.5026880460053854]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v = string[string.index('[') + 1:].split(',')
```

`index()` return index of given character, so that `'['` is included in sequence returned by `[:]`.